# Ill-formed C++0x code or compiler bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, sfinae

In the following C++0x code I tried to clone an object by using a
clone member function (if it exists) and falling back on a copy
constructor:

```
struct use_copy_ctor {};
struct prefer_clone_func : use_copy_ctor {};

template<class T>
auto clone(T const* ptr, prefer_clone_func)
-> decltype(ptr->clone())
{ return ptr->clone(); }

template<class T>
auto clone(T const* ptr, use_copy_ctor)
-> decltype(new T(*ptr))
{ return new T(*ptr); }

struct abc {
  virtual ~abc() {}
  virtual abc* clone() const =0;
};

struct derived : abc
{
  derived* clone() const { return new derived(*this); }
};

int main()
{
  derived d;
  abc* p = &d;
  abc* q = clone(p,prefer_clone_func());
  delete q;
}
```

The idea is to use auto...->decltype(expr) to weed out ill-formed
expressions as part of the template argument deduction (SFINAE) and to
resolve a possible ambiguity between both clone function templates via
partial ordering w.r.t. the second function parameter.

Unfortunately, GCC 4.5.1 doesn't accept this program:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:28:39: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type
  'abc'
test.cpp:14:12: note:   because the following virtual functions are
  pure within 'abc':
test.cpp:16:16: note:        virtual abc* abc::clone() const
test.cpp:28:39: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type
  'abc'
test.cpp:14:12: note:   since type 'abc' has pure virtual functions
```

Now, the question is, is this a compiler bug or was I wrong to assume
that SFINAE applies here? I'd appreciate an answer with a solid reasoning.

**Edit:**
If I change `decltype(new T(*ptr))` to `T*` the code compiles because of overload resolution preferring the first function template in this case. But this defeats the purpose of having the expression as part of the function declaration. The purpose is to make the compiler kick the function out of the overload resolution set in case of an error.

Comment: I'd take the "selection" argument by reference, since inheritance is involved. Not that it would solve your issue...

Comment: @Matthieu: by reference is not necessary to make this tag dispatching work. The partial ordering overload resolution rule still applies. I havn't checked how this is optimized by the compiler but libstdc++ also uses tag dispatching without references to implement std::advance, for example.

Comment: I know it's not required, I would still do it out of habit, I guess, to avoid the object slicing (not that a tag is supposed to have any data / methods...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I convinced myself that this is actually a compiler bug and filed a [report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47513). Let's see what happens. As a workaround `decltype(new T(*ptr))` can be replaced with `T*`. The only difference is that the function template will stay part of the overload resolution set which is not a big issue in this case.

**Edit**: Btw, I was told that clang++ accepts the above code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem with MSVC, and it turned out that the compiler wouldn't recognize my co-variant return types in the virtual function. Try changing `derived`'s definition of clone to returning an `abc`.

Comment: This doesn't help. `derived` is not abstract. I even create an object of type `derived` in the main function.